# Simple Regex text replace then add suffix

Tags: regex, replace

Im have a program that vbcan only handle basic regex no C# vb.net etc.
This is my situation.

I have a set of start Urls.
http://www.foo.com?code=234654

I need to remove the ?code= and replace with a / then add the letter t at the end.

Like this:
http://www.foo.com/234654t

I would appreciate any help this this. 
Thanks 
Sean

Comment: its simple. Split by & and ? and then for each array , split by = as delimiter and construct by appending it to base url.

Comment: thanks for your response, the base url changes, also its the actual syntax im struggling with.

Comment: What language is this written in?  String replace "?code=" with "/" and append "t" to the string is the simplest answer but not very robust.

Comment: Sorry it has to be simple RegEx

Comment: Try [`\?code=([^& ]*)` and replace with `/$1t`](https://regex101.com/r/mY1hX0/1)

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, however its not quite working .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the dialect that is used in [`java.util.regex`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html) you can use this regular expression, for example:

```
String regex = "\\?+[A-Za-z=]+([0-9]+)(?<=[0-9]+)(?=$)";
String replacement = "/$1t";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(line);
if (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.replaceAll(replacement));
}
```

Another example, by using [`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)):

```
line.replaceAll("\\?+[A-Za-z=]+", "/").replaceAll("(?<=[0-9|/]+)(?=$)", "t");
```

For the string:

`String line = "http://www.foo.com?code=234654";`

You'll get:

`http://www.foo.com/234654t`